# if-statement not working as i expected

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, if-statement

following code is not working. no error message or anything.. it just istn working. (images are not shown where they are supposed to be)
imgdtl is a NSMutableDictionary

```
        if ([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[filePath pathExtension]] == @".jpg")
        {
            NSImage *myimage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@" ,filePath]];
            [imgdtl setObject: myimage forKey: @"image"];
            [imgdtl setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@" ,fileName] forKey: @"filename"];
        }
        else{
            NSImage *myimage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:@"no_image.gif"];
            [imgdtl setObject: myimage forKey: @"image"];
            [imgdtl setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@" ,fileName] forKey: @"filename"];
        }
```

but this one is working:

```
            NSImage *myimage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@" ,filePath]];
            [imgdtl setObject: myimage forKey: @"image"];
            [imgdtl setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@" ,fileName] forKey: @"filename"];
```

i would like to load the image only if the format is .jpg and would like it not to load if the file has any other extension. could somebody please tell me what i am doing wrong? thanks!

**---EDIT---**

thanks to all the comments, but the following code gives the same problem as the one above:

```
     if ([[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[filePath pathExtension]] isEqualToString @".jpg"])
```

Comment: Please stop using `stringWithFormat` unless you actually have a string to format. It should be `if ([[filePath pathExtension] isEqualToString:@"jpg"])`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are hundreds of duplicates.

You want to compare the contents of a string, not the pointers.
 == compares pointers. To compare contents use NSString's `-isEqualToString:` method

```
if ([string isEqualToString :@"other string"]) .....
```

**edit**

On a side note, move your duplicate code out of your conditional blocks,
They are the same, so no need to put them there twice:

```
NSImage *myImage;

if ([[filePath pathExtension] isEqualToString: @"jpg"])
    {
        myImage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: filePath]];

    }
    else{
        myImage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:@"no_image.gif"];
    }

[imgdtl setObject: myImage forKey: @"image"];
[imgdtl setObject: fileName forKey: @"filename"];
```

Comment: thanks! sorry if this has already been answered but without knowing the problem i have no clue what to search for. i accept your answer in a few minutes as soon as the system allows me to do so..

Comment: sorry, talked to soon.. tried this one and still isnt working, must be something else wrong.. `  if ([[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[filePath pathExtension]] isEqualToString:@".jpg"])`

Comment: pathExtension will not return the period.  Also there is no reason to be making a new string first.

Comment: @KenAspeslagh is right. And people here often use the [stringWithFormat:@"%@", string] instead of just string.... See my edited answer with some improvements to your code.

Comment: thanks! the period was the problem! thank you very much!

Comment: thanks also for the updated code! its working liek a charm! i still have a problem on the no_image.gif since its not loading but i will figure that out on my own! thanks to all of you guys!

Comment: @Justme: FYI, the first "Related" post in the sidebar contains the answer. Glancing at the related answers Stack Overflow recommends will very often give you your answer very quickly.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried using the method "isEqualToString:" in the if statement? NSString has an isEqualToString method that compares two strings character for character instead of use the == operator. It sometimes returns different results.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following objective-c method: [someString isEqualToString:someOtherString]  to compare you strings

Answer (score 1):

```
if ([[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[filePath pathExtension]] isEqualToString @".jpg"])
        {
            NSImage *myimage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@" ,filePath]];
            [imgdtl setObject: myimage forKey: @"image"];
            [imgdtl setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@" ,fileName] forKey: @"filename"];
        }
        else{
            NSImage *myimage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:@"no_image.gif"];
            [imgdtl setObject: myimage forKey: @"image"];
            [imgdtl setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@" ,fileName] forKey: @"filename"];
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should compare strings like this:

```
if ([[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
    [filePath pathExtension]] isEqualToString:@"jpg"])
```

...because `==` is a pointer comparison and you are (this time) interested in content of two text strings instead of whether they are pointing to same memory location.

Comment: pathExtension will not return the period so this will never be true

Comment: Thanx, fixed. Just copy-pasted a line from original code, should have checked again